# lateinit property googleMap has not been initialized when calling a fragment function from mainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to create a mapping app in kotlin and here is my code

`MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var frMain : FrameLayout
    val utils = utils()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        frMain = findViewById(R.id.frMain)

        val fragMan = supportFragmentManager
        val fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction()
        val mapFragment = map(this)

        fragTrans.add(R.id.frMain,mapFragment)
        fragTrans.commit()
    }

    fun enablePermissionAngGetLocation() {
        if (!utils.isGPSEnabled(this@MainActivity)) {
            utils.showToastMessage(this@MainActivity,"Please turn on your GPS")
            return
        }

        val permissionlistener: PermissionListener = object : PermissionListener {
            override fun onPermissionGranted() {
                val locationUtils = locationUtils(this@MainActivity)

                locationUtils.requestLocationUpdates(object : locationUtils.LocationListener {
                    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                        val latitude = location.latitude
                        val longitude = location.longitude


                        map(this@MainActivity).moveCamera(latitude, longitude)
                    }

                    override fun onLocationRequestDenied() {
                        // Handle permission denied error
                    }
                })
            }

            override fun onPermissionDenied(deniedPermissions: MutableList<String>?) {
                utils.showToastMessage(this@MainActivity,"Some permissions were denied. Unable to use this function")
            }
        }

        TedPermission.with(this@MainActivity)
            .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
            .setDeniedMessage("GPS is required.\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
            .setPermissions(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .check()
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the `fragment`

```
class map(private val mainActivity: MainActivity) : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private lateinit var rlMain: RelativeLayout
    private lateinit var mapView: View
    private lateinit var rvEventMenu: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var crdGPS: CardView
    private lateinit var mapViewCavite: MapView


    private val eventList = ArrayList<eventItem>()
    private var eventAdapter: eventAdapter? = null
    private val mapAPIService = restApiService()
    private val utils = utils()

    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    private var isMapReady = false

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mapView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

        rlMain = mapView.findViewById(R.id.rlMain)
        rvEventMenu = mapView.findViewById(R.id.rvEventMenu)
        crdGPS = mapView.findViewById(R.id.crdGPS)
        mapViewCavite = mapView.findViewById(R.id.mapCavite)

        mapViewCavite.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapViewCavite.getMapAsync(this)

        crdGPS.setOnClickListener {
            mainActivity.enablePermissionAngGetLocation()
        }

        return mapView
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
        googleMap = map
        googleMap?.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN

        val location = LatLng(14.4791, 120.8970)
        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(location)
            .zoom(15.0f)
            .bearing(45.0f)
            .build()
        googleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
        loadMarkers()

        if (eventList.size != 0) {
            loadMenu()
        }
    }


    fun loadMarkers(selectedEventId: Int = 0) {
        if (!utils.hasInternet(requireContext())) {
            utils.showToastMessage(requireContext(), "Please check your internet connection")
            return
        }

        mapAPIService.getAllMarkers { response ->
            if (response!!.success) {
                val data = response.data
                if (data.rows_returned != 0) {
                    val events = data.event

                    googleMap?.clear()

                    events.forEach { event ->
                        val eventName: String = event.event
                        val lat: Double = event.lat.toDouble()
                        val lng: Double = event.lng.toDouble()
                        val iconUrl: String = event.link

                        eventList.add(eventItem(event.id, iconUrl, eventName))

                        if (selectedEventId == 0 || selectedEventId == event.id) {
                            Glide.with(requireContext())
                                .asBitmap()
                                .load(iconUrl)
                                .apply(RequestOptions().override(100, 100))
                                .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                        val bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)
                                        googleMap?.addMarker(
                                            MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(LatLng(lat, lng))
                                                .icon(bitmapDescriptor)
                                        )
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    }

                    if (eventList.isNotEmpty() && eventAdapter == null) {
                        loadMenu()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadMenu() {
        val eventListDistinct: ArrayList<eventItem> = eventList.distinct() as ArrayList<eventItem>
        eventAdapter = eventAdapter(this, eventListDistinct)
        rvEventMenu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        rvEventMenu.adapter = eventAdapter
    }

    fun moveCamera(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
        val newLatLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
        val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng, 15f)
        googleMap?.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        activity?.window?.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
        activity?.window?.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapViewCavite.onResume()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapViewCavite.onStart()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapViewCavite.onStop()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapViewCavite.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapViewCavite.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapViewCavite.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

Actually the code works. It loads the map and add markers however I want to go to my current position and the function is in here

```
crdGPS.setOnClickListener {
            mainActivity.enablePermissionAngGetLocation()
        }
```

get the current lat long in main activity and pass it back in my function inside the `fragment`

then the error start showing. Maybe because im calling the fragment againso that why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error, because in this part of the `Activity` you're creating a new instance of Fragment instead of pass the data to already attached one:

```
                override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                    val latitude = location.latitude
                    val longitude = location.longitude

                    // HERE! you're creating new Fragment instance, which has not initialized googleMap
                    map(this@MainActivity).moveCamera(latitude, longitude)
                }

                override fun onLocationRequestDenied() {
                    // Handle permission denied error
                }
            })
```

Instead, you should use other methods to interact with your already created Fragment. For example, you can use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts):

In your `Activity`:

```
                override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                    val latitude = location.latitude
                    val longitude = location.longitude
                    
                    sendBroadcast(Intent().apply {
                      action = "some_action"
                      putExtra("lat", latitude)
                      putExtra("lng", longitude)
                    })
                }

                override fun onLocationRequestDenied() {
                    // Handle permission denied error
                }
            })
```

In your `Fragment`:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
       ...
        private val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            val lat = p1?.extras?.getFloat("lat")
            val lng = p1?.extras?.getFloat("lng")
            // Handle your interaction with map here
        }


        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            ...
            requireActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("some_action"))
            ...
        }

        override fun onDestroyView() {
             ...
             requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
}
```

You can use different methods to pass data to your Fragment, including just get the referrence to the fragment via `FragmentManager`. The main thing is that you don't have to create new Fragments as you're doing now.

**Note**

1. You shouldn't pass `Activity` reference to your Fragment. Your fragment will get it after attaching to `Context` and you will be able to get referrence to your `Activity` with `Fragment.requireActivity()` method
2. You should name your Fragments like ...Fragment (for example, MapFragment) in order to improve the readability of your code.